# Making a set up screen on first start up

Tags: android, eclipse, passwords

I'm here today asking someone if they know a way to make a set up screen on first start up.

Here's the scenario: When someone downloads my app and uses it for the first time, it has to show a method where users make a password. On subsequent uses, I don't want it to be shown anymore. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: I hope you're hashing and salting the password.

Comment: @SLaks "salting and hashing"?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Yes when storing a password you should never store the password itself, but store the hashed value of the password + a salt value (random or not).You can find lot of questions about Hashing and Salting on SO.

Comment: @VincentB. yes, I know lol. I was questioning his order of operations.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Ah, ok, your "question" was quite misleading, but yes, the comment of SLaks is indeed to take in consideration but is far from answering our user question. However with all those PW hash stolen those days, good to keep it in mind !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SharedPreferences` for this purpose.

At the start of your application, check if the key "myKey+versioncode" is present or not in the SharedPreferences. If it not stored, then it means your application has not bee started yet, let the user create his/her password. Once the password is created, add the `SharedPreferences` "myKey+versioncode" with any value you like, and next time you will find this `SharedPreferences`, so it means the user already started the application and created its password.

However be careful about the "versionning" of this key, you might also want to keep a single key instead of one per version of your application.

Edit: Concept found at the time I was looking  for EULA inplementation, here: [Simple EULA implementation for Android](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2011/02/17/android-a-simple-eula-for-your-android-apps/)